# How can I get the full path of a file in windows explorer?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Windows 10 professional, When I want to copy the full path of a file|folder, I have to first copy the URL from the windows explorer then append the file/folder name and its extension.

Is there a convenient way to copy the full path of a file|folder directly from windows explorer? Additionally, how can I open a PowerShell|CMD window from it?

Comment: Downvoters, are there any suggestions to improve the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Path of the File/Folder by Right-Clicking > Properties > Location
If you want to open the File/Folder in PowerShell then use `cd C:\\Desktop\Your_File_Location`

Answer (score 5):

To copy the `full path` for an individual file, hold down the **`Shift`** key as you **`right-click`** the file, and then choose `Copy As Path`. 
[image]